# How to pass a compile-time Maven defined property to a spring-boot application?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

When I was using the war plugin I could do:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

And in my src/main/resources I had a file (build.properties) to map this to a Spring Environment property:

```
build.revision=${buildNumber}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with the spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Comment: If you are inheriting from `spring-boot-starter-parent`, you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417086/maven-resource-filtering-could-not-resolve-placeholder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using `spring-boot-starter-parent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven) gives you (according to documentation)

> Sensible resource filtering for application.properties and application.yml including profile-specific files (e.g. application-foo.properties and application-foo.yml)". Since the default config files accept Spring style placeholders (${…​}) the Maven filtering is changed to use @..@ placeholders (you can override that with a Maven property resource.delimiter).

So, a `@buildNumber@` in application.properties might work for you.

I am not sure how "sensible filtering" works for other (non-application-config) resource files (such as your `build.properties`). Maybe try it there, too.

---

Pure Maven option:

You can [opt in to the Maven resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html):

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

This will rewrite your `${variable}` expressions.

If you have files in there that should not receive this treatment (such as those that contain runtime placeholders, or binary files), you can also set up a separate `resources-filtered` directory.

Comment: Yes replacing ${___} with @___@ worked like a charm, thanks! Totally missed that part of doc...

Comment: For the record, in Spring Boot 1.4 you'll have [support for a dedicated build info task](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-build-info). This is available for both Maven and Gradle.